# Operation prohibited on supervised devices

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

On one of my 5th Generation iPod I am getting the "Operation prohibited on supervised devices" error message from XCode when I attach the device to my MAC. Any idea why is this error coming and how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Apple document explains the different settings and how to change between them:

http://images.apple.com/au/iphone/business/docs/iOS_Apple_Configurator_Mar12.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to make sure that your development devices aren't supervised: see [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4751026?start=0&tstart=0).

You'll likely have to chase this up with whoever manages your device.